# Create a combined chart in pygal?

Tags: python, pygal

Is it possible to create a single chart with a line series and a bar series?

```
chart = pygal.Line()
chart.x_labels = 'Red', 'Blue', 'Green'
chart.y_labels = .0001, .0003, .0004, .00045, .0005
chart.add('line', [.0002, .0005, .00035])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer can be found in the documentation at http://www.pygal.org/en/stable/documentation/web.html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- ... -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <figure>
       <embed type="image/svg+xml" src="/mysvg.svg" />
    </figure>
  </body>
</html>
```

Duplicating the line in the `<figure>` tag allows you to vertically combine your charts, aligning at the left of the screen. With CSS, and defining two figure tags you can then align horizontally the two figures.

Answer (score 1):

In response to your query from pygal's github issue tracker: **no**

https://github.com/Kozea/pygal/issues/46

Comment: and it looks like the commits since that issue was raised did not add that ability.